# Resample a time-series data at the end of the month and at the end of the day

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have a timeseries data with the following format.

| **DateShort (%d/%m/%Y)** | **TimeFrom** | **TimeTo** | **Value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2018 | 0:00 | 1:00 | 6414 |
| 1/1/2018 | 1:00 | 2:00 | 6153 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1/1/2018 | 23:00 | 0:00 | 6317 |
| 2/1/2018 | 0:00 | 1:00 | 6046 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I would like to re-sample data at the end of the month **and** at the end of the day.

The dataset could be retrieved from https://pastebin.com/raw/NWdigN97

`pandas.DataFrame.resample()` provides `'M'` rule to retrieve data from the end of the month but at the beginning of the day.
See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Do you have better solution to accomplish this?

I have the following sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ds_url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/NWdigN97'

df = pd.read_csv(ds_url, header=0)

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['DateShort'] + ' ' + df['TimeFrom'],
    format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
)

df.drop('DateShort', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)

df.resample('M').asfreq()
```

The output is

```
           TimeFrom TimeTo  Value
DateTime                         
2018-01-31     0:00   1:00   7215
2018-02-28     0:00   1:00   8580
2018-03-31     0:00   1:00   6202
2018-04-30     0:00   1:00   5369
2018-05-31     0:00   1:00   5840
2018-06-30     0:00   1:00   5730
2018-07-31     0:00   1:00   5979
2018-08-31     0:00   1:00   6009
2018-09-30     0:00   1:00   5430
2018-10-31     0:00   1:00   6587
2018-11-30     0:00   1:00   7948
2018-12-31     0:00   1:00   6193
```

However, the correct output should be

```
           TimeFrom TimeTo  Value
DateTime                            
2018-01-31  23:00   0:00    7605
2018-02-28  23:00   0:00    8790
2018-03-31  23:00   0:00    5967
2018-04-30  23:00   0:00    5595
2018-05-31  23:00   0:00    5558
2018-06-30  23:00   0:00    5153
2018-07-31  23:00   0:00    5996
2018-08-31  23:00   0:00    5757
2018-09-30  23:00   0:00    5785
2018-10-31  23:00   0:00    6437
2018-11-30  23:00   0:00    7830
2018-12-31  23:00   0:00    6767
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).last()
```

Output:

```
           TimeFrom TimeTo  Value
DateTime                         
2018-01-31    23:00   0:00   7605
2018-02-28    23:00   0:00   8790
2018-03-31    23:00   0:00   5967
2018-04-30    23:00   0:00   5595
2018-05-31    23:00   0:00   5558
2018-06-30    23:00   0:00   5153
2018-07-31    23:00   0:00   5996
2018-08-31    23:00   0:00   5757
2018-09-30    23:00   0:00   5785
2018-10-31    23:00   0:00   6437
2018-11-30    23:00   0:00   7830
2018-12-31    23:00   0:00   6707
```